# vue-tsc and volar conflicts due to version. how can I solve this issue?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm having vsCode letting me know there's a issue here:

> ❗ Different vue-tsc version The Vue Language Features (Volar)'s
> version is 1.0.9, but the workspace's vue-tsc version is 0.39.5. This
> may produce different type checking behavior.
>
> vue-tsc:
> /home/tomas/Desktop/testingthekid/viteFiles/typescript/typescript-and-vue-workshop/app/node_modules/vue-tsc/package.json

So I googled it and found a similar problem which was resolved installing the latest version of vue-tsc, you know, both are the same and problem should be gone. In my case i did it and the .json file changed, indeed now is  `"vue-tsc": "^1.0.9"` but the problem still there even if i do **ctrl+c and npm run dev** again, might be that this: **ctrl+c and npm run dev** is not the proper way to restart the server? Why is vscode not addresing the version change?
here's a pic:
[image]

You can see the error and the vue-tsc version.
This another one I catch => might be the problem:
[image]

How can I solve this issue, thank you in advance & every answer/suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you restart vscode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the command palette (ctrl+shift+P) and click `Volar: Restart Vue server`

[image]